# Многотабличный вложенный SQL-запрос

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть вот такой многотабличный запрос, который верно работает:

```
(select max([faculty].[id_fac]) as [id_fac] ,max([name_fac]) as [name_fac] ,count(*)   as [count_students] from [student] JOIN [student_group] ON [student].[id_student] = [student_group]. [id_student] 
JOIN [group] ON [student_group].[id_group] = [group].[id_group]
JOIN [spec] ON [group].[id_spec] = [spec].[id_spec]
JOIN [chair] ON [spec].[id_chair] = [chair].[id_chair]
JOIN [faculty] ON [chair].[id_fac] = [faculty].[id_fac]
group by [faculty].[id_fac])
```

Далее этот запрос вкладывается в следующий :

```
 (select max([fac_stud].[count_students]) as [max_count_stud] from <запрос_выше> as [fac_stud])
```

Тут тоже все хорошо. Затем все это вкладывается в последний 3-ий запрос:

```
 select [fac_stud].[name_fac] where [fac_stud].[count_students] = <запрос_выше(2)>
```

И этот запрос уже не работает, ошибки:

> `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The multi-part identifier "fac_stud.count_students" could not be bound.
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The multi-part identifier "fac_stud.name_fac" could not be bound.`

То есть сначала я делаю соединение, группировку и выборку, получая таблицу `[fac_stud]` (запрос 1), затем из этой таблицы нахожу максимум по колонке `[count_students]`, а потом хочу вернутся к 1-ой таблице `[fac_stud]` и сделать выборку из неё, но она как будто не доступна непонятно почему.

И еще 2-ой вопрос, если можно: в запросе 1, когда применяю агрегатную функцию к 1-ой колонке для данной группы и есть 2 другие колонки, значения которых одинаковы для всех строк данной группы, как их можно выбрать без применения функции max, как в моем случае?

Заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Так не получится. Вы получаете выборку `max_count_stud` уже без id и `name_fac`, соответственно эти поля уже доступны не будут, про них забыли.
2. Перенесите эти поля в `group by`.

Попробуйте так:

```
select top 1 * from 
  (select [faculty].[id_fac] as [id_fac],
          [faculty].[name_fac] as [name_fac],
          count([student].[id_student]) as [count_students] 
   from [student] 
          JOIN [student_group] ON [student].[id_student] = [student_group].[id_student] 
          JOIN [group] ON [student_group].[id_group] = [group].[id_group]
          JOIN [spec] ON [group].[id_spec] = [spec].[id_spec]
          JOIN [chair] ON [spec].[id_chair] = [chair].[id_chair]
          JOIN [faculty] ON [chair].[id_fac] = [faculty].[id_fac]
   group by [faculty].[id_fac], [faculty].[name_fac]) as faculty_students_count
order by [count_students] desc
```

Comment: А если максимум не 1 ?) можно конечно писать top 10(100;1000) , но это мне кажется не совсем правильным

Comment: Ну да, если больше одного, не подходит. Значит надо получить сначала значение этого максимума, потом вложенный запрос отфильтровать по этому максимуму. Получится дублирование подзапроса.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое уточнение:

```
select top (1) with ties * from 
  (select [faculty].[id_fac] as [id_fac],
          [faculty].[name_fac] as [name_fac],
          count([student].[id_student]) as [count_students] 
   from [student] 
          JOIN [student_group] ON [student].[id_student] = [student_group].[id_student] 
          JOIN [group] ON [student_group].[id_group] = [group].[id_group]
          JOIN [spec] ON [group].[id_spec] = [spec].[id_spec]
          JOIN [chair] ON [spec].[id_chair] = [chair].[id_chair]
          JOIN [faculty] ON [chair].[id_fac] = [faculty].[id_fac]
   group by [faculty].[id_fac], [faculty].[name_fac]) as faculty_students_count
order by [count_students] desc
```

При таком запросе, если максимальное количество будет совпадать у нескольких записей, будут выведены все записи с максимальным количеством